# How to connect with Mobile Broadband using a Verizon LG USB

Tags: 12.04, mobile-broadband

I have an LG-VL600 VZW broadband USB adapter that my company provides and it is activated and working on Windows7 but can't get it working in Ubuntu 12.04. I've created a mobile broadband connection in Network Connections and have all the settings setup as I believe they should be according to [this](http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2009/01/ubuntu-rocks-mobile-broadband.html) Raving Rick blog post.

I'm not sure how to use this connection though. The broadband connection never shows in the list of connections to connect to and I don't see any option to 'Enable Mobile Broadband' -though I'm not sure if that is supposed to be there or not.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for like 1 or 2 minutes after pluging-in the broadband adapter, to see if the connection shows up in the network manager? I also have a USB Broadband adapter (not Verizon nor LG) and sometimes it takes a lot to show up.

Comment: @amfcosta - yes I've waited several minutes.